Return on Puppeteer's event listener
I have a simple issue which I am not able to solve for last couple of days... I need to pack page on response inside a separate function called setupRequestInterception. When I do that the code is not working, I get a timeout.
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const setupRequestInterception = async (page) => {
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        page.on('request', (request) => {
            request.continue();
        });

        page.on('response', async (response) => {
            const headers = response.headers();

            resolve(headers); // Resolve the promise with the headers
        });

        page.on('close', () => {
            reject(new Error('Page closed before headers could be intercepted.'));
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error('Timeout reached before headers could be intercepted.'));
        }, 10000); // Set a timeout to prevent hanging
    });
};

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        const headers = await setupRequestInterception(page);
        await page.goto('https://google.com');
        console.log('Intercepted Headers:', headers);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err.message);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();

But when I do that like this, it works.
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        const headers = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            page.on('response', async (response) => {
                const headers = response.headers();
    
                resolve(headers); // Resolve the promise with the headers
            });
    
            page.on('close', () => {
                reject(new Error('Page closed before headers could be intercepted.'));
            });
    
            setTimeout(() => {
                reject(new Error('Timeout reached before headers could be intercepted.'));
            }, 10000); // Set a timeout to prevent hanging
        });

        await page.goto('https://google.com');
        console.log('Intercepted Headers:', headers);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err.message);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();


Sorry, what is the question? Seems like you have the solution already, although keep in mind waitForResponse/waitForRequest are promisified page.on("request", page.on("response"s.

Also, this pattern leaks memory--the handlers are never removed and will always resolve to the first response. I'm not sure why you'd do this, since goto is pretty much guaranteed to be the response you'd send, but it already returns it. More details seem necessary here.

The second example indeed solves the issue, although I need to keep this Promise in a separate function to maintain a clean code. The examples I provided are only to showcase the problem.
page.waitForResponse also doesn't work.
Thanks for pointing out event listener removal. I am aware of that, I just simplified the code to show only the issue.

Here's the code using waitForResponse:
const sri = async (page) => {
return await page.waitForResponse(response => {
return response.headers();
});
};
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
try {
    const headers = await sri(page);
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    console.log('Intercepted Headers:', headers);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err.message);
} finally {
    await browser.close();
}

})();

Can you [edit] the post to share that? Thanks. Do you realize that const response = await page.goto("...") is entirely possible so you don't have to intercept anything? I guess I still don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.

I don't see how the bottom code could possibly work, because the promise is never awaited. Also, any time you have a function that's marked async and you never use the await keyword in it, just remove the async. On a few levels, the code here doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

I most definitely don't know how to approach what I want to achieve. If the site is blocked from indexing by x-robots-tag (which is in response header) I need to be able to abort the request asap to prevent from indexing it and also utilizing my compute resources.

That goal wasn't part of the original question. Can you [edit] it to first clarify exactly what you want to achieve, provide a site that gives this x-robots-tag, and explain what "indexing" means in this context? Then provide the code with a clear problem and question. Let me know once that's done and I'll try to help. Thanks.
